# Ubuntu 20.04.2 as VM autologin hangs

Tags: login, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I have an Ubuntu 20.04.2 Desktop with KVM installed. I then installed Ubuntu 20.04.2 Desktop as VM. I have it setup, so that an auto login on tty6 starts. It kinda of works. The VM boots and stays on tty6, but will not login. When I switch to tty1 and back to tty6, then it logs in. I have tried setting the Video on the KVM, all 3. I installed the guest agent on the VM. I can't find any errors.
When it boots, the last thing I see is "Finished Terminate Plymouth Boot Screen". Then I switch to tty1 and back to tty6, and then continues. Does anybody have Idea?

Comment: Hello. A good place to start is you are behind in updates. An up to date Ubuntu system would report 20.04.4

Comment: I hate answers like this. Does that mean it never worked? Because of the policies we have here, I can not do Updates.

Comment: If you do not do updates you are at risk of most importantly security issues. I do not understand your comment to me, it does not reference anything I wrote.

Comment: I have a script in "/etc/init.d/NAME". At the end of this script, I added the following: chvt 1; sleep 10; chvt 6.  Now it works. But I still don't know why I have to add this. As far as the Updates go, we are aware of this. But since most of our systems have no direct connection with the internet, they are not worried about it.